# MongoDB unwinding 2 embedded arrays separately

Tags: mongodb

I have a question regarding MongoDB aggregation query which is almost similar to [$unwind 2 fields separately in mongodb query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153622/unwind-2-fields-seperately-in-mongodb-query).

This is the document:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "details" : {
        "phonenumber" : [
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "name" : [
            "a",
            "b"
        ]
    }
}
```

And I am trying to frame a query which will return me the following result:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "phonenumber" : "1", "name" : null },
{ "_id" : "1", "phonenumber" : "2", "name" : null },
{ "_id" : "1", "phonenumber" : null, "name" : "a" },
{ "_id" : "1", "phonenumber" : null, "name" : "b" }
```

**Could someone please help me with that?**

Closest solution I could figure out is by following query:

```
db.document.aggregate( [ { $unwind: { path: "$details.name"} }, { $unwind: { path: "$details.phonenumber" } }, { $project: { _id: 1, name: "$details.name", phonenumber: "$details.phonenumber" } } ] )
```

And the output from above query is:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "phonenumber" : "1", "name" : "a" },
{ "_id" : "1", "phonenumber" : "1", "name" : "b" },
{ "_id" : "1", "phonenumber" : "2", "name" : "a" },
{ "_id" : "1", "phonenumber" : "2", "name" : "b" }
```

Comment: Can you give a full example of a document in your collection? In your attempt, you have `$details.email`.

Comment: Aggregation pipelining is sequential. The output of one stage will become input to another. What you are trying to do is branching the initial data into two stages. That is not possible.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I have edited in the question the 'email' field with 'name'. It was a typo.

Comment: @RaR Is it possible to get the output I am expecting by any other way or not?

Comment: @AmitValse Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @RaR I am using 3.4 only. And your solution works well :) , but it wasn't as per my requirement, so I have edited your solution to reflect the result I was expecting. Please approve the changes so I can accept your solution.

Comment: @AmitValse approved :) Sorry. I missed to cross-check.

Comment: Thank you very much @RaR for the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `MongoDB v3.4`, one of the possible solution would be,

```
db.document.aggregate({
    '$facet': {
        'phonenumber': [{
            '$unwind': '$details.phonenumber'
        }, {
            '$project': {
                phonenumber: '$details.phonenumber',
                name: null
            }
        }],
        'name': [{
            '$unwind': '$details.name'
        }, {
            '$project': {
                name: '$details.name',
                phonenumber: null
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'combined': {
            '$setUnion': ['$phonenumber', '$name']
        }
    }
}, {
    '$unwind': '$combined'
}, {
    '$replaceRoot': {
        'newRoot': '$combined'
    }
})
```

[facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#facet-aggregation) allows us to include multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage, which is available from version 3.4

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution for earlier versions of mongodb,

```
    db.document.aggregate([{
        $unwind: {
            path: "$details.name"
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            nameArr: {
                $push: {
                    name: "$details.name",
                    phonenumber: {
                        $ifNull: ["$description", null]
                    }
                }
            },
            "details": {
                $first: "$details"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$details.phonenumber"
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            phoneArr: {
                $push: {
                    phonenumber: "$details.phonenumber",
                    name: {
                        $ifNull: ["$description", null]
                    }
                }
            },
            "nameArr": {
                $first: "$nameArr"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            value: {
                $setUnion: ["$nameArr", "$phoneArr"]
            }
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$value"
    }, {
        $project: {
            name: "$value.name",
            phonenumber: "$value.phonenumber"
        }
    }])
```